# Secure specific react page using keycloak

Tags: reactjs, keycloak, keycloak-connect

I am building a demon project of authentication whith Keycloak into a react project.
I have one public page and a private one.
The private page check if the user is logged in and display a button to log in or to log out, depending the connection state. This part works well. When I click on the log in button I am redirected to the Keycloak portal. After login, I am redirected to the private page and I can log out with the apropriated button.

But when I navigate to the public page and go back to the private, or just refreshing the private page, the connection seems to be out. Then I click on the log in button and the connection come back, without been redirected to the keycloak portal.

There the private page :

```
import React from "react";
import Nav from "../modules/Nav";
import RenderAnonymous from "../modules/RenderAnonymous";
import RenderAuthenticated from "../modules/RenderAuthenticated";
import UserService from "../services/UserService";

const Private = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <Nav/>
            <RenderAnonymous>
                <p>Il faut s'authentifier</p>
                <button onClick={UserService.doLogin} className="btn login-btn">Se connecter</button>
            </RenderAnonymous>
            <RenderAuthenticated>
                <p>User info</p>
                <button onClick={UserService.doLogout} className="btn login-btn">Déconnexion</button>
            </RenderAuthenticated>
            <div className="private">
                <h2>Page privée</h2>
            </div>
        </>
    );
};

export default Private;
```

RenderAnonymous and RenderAuthenticated are the same expect the authentication condition :

```
import UserService from "../services/UserService";

const RenderAuthenticated = ({children}) => {
    if (UserService.isAuthenticated()) {
        return (children);
    }
    return null;
};


export default RenderAuthenticated;
```

UserService :

```
import keycloak from "keycloak-js";

const KC = new keycloak("/keycloak.json");

const initKeycloak = (authenticatedCllback) => {
    KC.init({
        onLoad: "check-sso"
    }).then((auth)=>{
        if (auth) {
            console.info("Already logged in");
        } else {
            console.info("Need to log in");
        }
        authenticatedCllback();
    }).catch((err)=>{
        console.error(err);
    });
}

const doLogin = () => {
    return KC.login();
}

const doLogout = () => {
    return KC.logout();
}

const isAuthenticated = () => {
    return KC.authenticated;
}

const UserService = {
    initKeycloak,
    doLogin,
    doLogout,
    isAuthenticated,
};

export default UserService;
```

The inistialization of keycloak is launched from index.js :

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import UserService from "./services/UserService";

const renderApp = () => ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.getElementById("root"));

UserService.initKeycloak(renderApp);
```

I don't understand where is the problem...
Is it a problem of flow ? https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#_javascript_implicit_flow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my point of view, you should integrate the keycloak object (and the UserService) into react handling. At the moment it seems to live outside of your `<App/>`.

For example you can use [React context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) to hold the keycloak instance. But you do not need to implement this yourself. There is already a library called [react-keycloak](https://github.com/react-keycloak/react-keycloak/tree/master/packages/web) which implements this approach.

Comment: Thanks Matthias, I'll try this

Comment: I implemented react-keycloak but I have the same issue. The connection expires each time I refresh the page. I don't see any cookie or Authorization header attaching to the requests. Do I need to use something like redux ?

Comment: when you say "connection", do you mean, the token? If yes, of course the token has an expiry (TTL) and you need to take the refresh-token to get a new one. And by "refreshing the page" you mean Pressing F5 or CTRL-R? If yes, this is how it works. Everytime you load the page, keycloak roundtrip is done to receive a token, but usually this is not visible to the user.

Comment: When I say connection, it is about the result of the keycloak.authenticated property. What I don't understand is where the token is stored and how does react app work with it.

Comment: When I say refresh, yes it's F5. But the page refresh itself, arround each 5 seconds. I display a message indicates the authentication status (from keycloak.authenticated) and the button changes to display "Login" or "Logout". When the page refresh itself, the status turns to "No authenticated" and the button switches to "Login"

Comment: ok. Please try to understand the react context thing. This is, where the authentication information is stored. Of course, the context is lost, when you press F5. If you want to keep it, you need to handle it via cookie or localStorage.

Comment: UPDATE : It was not a problem of my code but it seems to be my Mozilla Firefox config which seems to block cookies from keycloak server. I tried whiyh Chrom without restrictions and it works well. I'm exporing this way